# ZF2 + Doctrine - Entities - how to access related data from an Entity and do something to it?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm working on an application with ZF2 and Doctrine that has 2 MySQL tables (with associated Doctrine Entities):

- Readings (contains a list of values received from Sensors)
- Sensors (contains the definition of the Sensors, how they are configured etc)

In my application, I have a view which lists the values from the Readings entity in date order. One of the columns, "r_value", needs to be converted using a formula that is stored in the Sensors table. If I can retrieve the appropriate value from the Sensors table, I can make a quick function (getConvertedValue()) to return the appropriately formatted data.

**What I'd like to do**
In my view, I'd like to call `$row->getConvertedValue()` in the same way I can call `$row->getRValue()`

**My questions are**

- What is the correct way to define the getConvertedValue() function?
- Where should it reside (in my Readings Entity, in a Repository which extends the Entity etc)?

Sorry if it's a basic question, but I can't seem to find a clear example to work from.

Comment: It's unclear if your two entities have associations with each other; It would be clearer if you update your question with the entity classes and any attempt you have made.

Comment: Noted - the entities do have an association. I'll update the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place the function inside the Readings entity:

```
<?php
class Readings
{
    public function getConvertedValue()
    {
        $formula = $this->getSensor()->getFormula();
        $value   = $this->getRValue();

        // Calculate $result using the formula

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I'm assuming a *-to-one relationship from the Readings entity to the Sonsors entity.

Comment: Thanks - I had defined my associations, but not well enough. Your post made it more obvious how I had to tweak my code.